# UITextView: characters count is not right when the backspace is typed in

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextviewdelegate

I want to show the characters number when I type in a UITextView.  But I'm confused when I presse the delete/backspace key.

I use:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

My code is:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSLog(@"input %d chars",textView.text.length + 1);
    return YES;
}
```

When I type in hello, it shows 'input 5 chars'; But if I click the delete/backspace key, the number become 6, not 4.  What's the matter with this?  How I can know the exact number of chars in the UITextView when I type in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty obvious :)

You're outputting the length+1

```
textView.text.length + 1
```

but a backspace doesn't make the length 1 longer, it makes it 1 shorter!

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text

    // Do the replacement
    NSString *newText = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

   // See what comes out
    NSLog(@"input %d chars", newText.length);

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  My method is just bad.  I add 1 because I think 1 is the text.length.  Now I know how to do it from your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the text that is going to be in text field after your edit and then check its length:

```
NSString* newString = [textField1.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
int newLength = [newString length];
```

Answer (score 2):

The text view sends `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` **before** it actually changes its text.

It sends `textViewDidChange:` **after** it changes its text.

So just implement `textViewDidChange:` instead:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSLog(@"textView.text.length = %u", textView.text.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the replacement text argument, which will be zero in case of a backspace.

There's another case to consider, where the user selects a range of characters and pastes text into the field.  In that case, you should also subtract out the length of the replaced text.

```
NSLog(@"New length is: %d chars",textView.text.length - range.length + text.length);
```

Comment: What if they selected 5 characters and cut them - then text.length will be 0 but the new length of the textView's text should be 5 less.

Comment: Good point-you have to factor in the length of the range too, which I forgot in in my haste.

Comment: I would just call `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:` and let iOS deal with it for me :)